# How to check Ajax request only when i opened the Notifications list?

Tags: ajax, notifications

I have this script from plugin i used "[DW Notifications](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dw-notifications/)", the problem i'm facing is the ajax auto check for new notifications working always on the front end and this makes my site loading too much.

So, How can i check the ajax only when the notification list is open?

I'm newbie with WordPress, and i searched more time to fix that problem but i failed.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var tempPopup;
    var time = dwnotif.dwnotif_current_time;
    var old_time = time;

    if(!$('#dw-notifications').length){
        return;
    }

    var change_numer = 0;
    var minTimeRequest = 2000;
    var maxTimeRequest = 30000;
    var currentTimeRequest = 10000;
    var timeoutPopup = 15000;


    autoCheck();

    function changeTimeRequest(changed = false){

        if(changed){
            currentTimeRequest = currentTimeRequest/2;
        }else{
            change_numer++;
            if(change_numer<5){
                return false;
            }
            currentTimeRequest = currentTimeRequest*2;
            change_numer = 0;
        }

        if(currentTimeRequest<minTimeRequest){
            currentTimeRequest = minTimeRequest;
        }

        if(currentTimeRequest>maxTimeRequest){
            currentTimeRequest = maxTimeRequest;
        }
    }



    function autoCheck(changed = false){
        changeTimeRequest(changed);
        changeTimeItem(time);
        changeReadItem();
        setTimeout(checkNotifications, currentTimeRequest);
    }

    function checkNotifications(){
        $.ajax({
            url: dwnotif.dwnotif_ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                action: 'dwnotif_check_notifications',
                nonce: dwnotif.dwnotif_nonce,
                time: time,
            },
            success: function( data ) {

                var changed = false;
                if (data.success) {
                    if(data.result.newest_notifications){
                        $('#dw-notifications .list-notification').prepend(data.result.newest_notifications);

                        if(data.result.count_unchecked){
                            $('#dw-notifications').find('.dw-notification-btn').addClass('has-notification');
                            $('#dw-notifications').find('.notif-count-unchecked').text(data.result.count_unchecked);
                        }

                        if(data.result.newest_notifications_popup){
                            addPopup(data.result.newest_notifications_popup);
                        }

                        changed = true;
                    }

                    /*if(data.result.length>0){
                        for(var i=0;i<data.result.length;i++){
                            $('.dw-notifications._' + data.result[i].id).find('.list-notification').html(data.result[i].html);
                            if(data.result[i].new){
                                addPopup(data.result[i].id, data.result[i].new);
                                changed = true;
                            }
                            if(data.result[i].count_unchecked){
                                addHasNotifications(data.result[i].id, data.result[i].count_unchecked);
                            }
                        }
                    }*/
                    time = data.time;
                }
                autoCheck(changed);
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                autoCheck(false);
            }
        });
    }

    function changeTimeItem(){
        $('.dw-notifications .list-notification').find('li').each(function(e){
            var diff= dw_human_time_diff($(this).data('time'), time);
            $(this).find('.notif-time').text(diff);
        });
    }

    function changeReadItem(){
        //change read all
        var markReadAll = getCookie('dw_read_all_time');
        if(markReadAll){
            // all read
            $('#dw-notifications .list-notification').find('.unread').each(function(){
                var item_time = $(this).data('time');
                if(item_time <= markReadAll){
                    $(this).removeClass('unread').addClass('read');
                }
            });
        }

        //change read item
        var readList = getCookie('dw_read_list');
        if(readList){
            var listItems = readList.split(",");
            for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++){
                $('#dw-notifications .list-notification').find('#dw-notif-' + listItems[i] + '.unread').removeClass('unread').addClass('read');
            }
        }

        //change has notification
        var checkedTime = getCookie('dw_checked_time');
        if(checkedTime && checkedTime >= old_time){
            $('#dw-notifications .dw-notification-btn').removeClass('has-notification');
        }
        old_time = time;
    }

    function addPopup(itemHtml){
        var popup_id = '#dw-notif-popup';
        if($(popup_id).length){

            $(popup_id).addClass('open');

            var item = $(itemHtml);
            //close popup notify
            item.on('click', function(){
                $(this).closest('.dw-notif-popup').remove();
            });
            $(popup_id +' ul').append(item);

            clearTimeout(tempPopup);
            tempPopup = setTimeout( function(){ $(popup_id).removeClass('open'); $(popup_id +' ul').html('');}, timeoutPopup);
        }

    }

    //user checked
    $('.dw-notification-btn').on('click', function(){

        $(this).removeClass('has-notification');

        var notifications = $(this).closest('.dw-notifications');

        if(notifications.hasClass('open')){
            notifications.removeClass('open');
        }else{
            notifications.addClass('open');

            if(!dwnotif.dwnotif_is_user_logged_in){
                //if user not logged => return false
                return false;
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: dwnotif.dwnotif_ajax_url,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    action: 'dwnotif_mark_user_checked',
                    nonce: dwnotif.dwnotif_nonce,
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    // if (data.success) {
                    //  //read all
                    //  notifications.find('.unread').addClass('read').removeClass('unread');
                    // }
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {

                }
            });
        }

    });

    //mark item read
    $(document).on('click', '.list-notification .unread', function (e) {
        $(this).removeClass('unread').addClass('read');
    }); 

    //mark all as read
    $('.dw-notif-mark-all-read').on('click', function(){
        var notifications = $(this).closest('.dw-notifications');
        var id = notifications.data('id');

        $.ajax({
            url: dwnotif.dwnotif_ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                action: 'dwnotif_mark_all_as_read',
                nonce: dwnotif.dwnotif_nonce,
                id: id,
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                if (data.success) {
                    //read all
                    notifications.find('.unread').addClass('read').removeClass('unread');
                }
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {

            }
        });
    });

    $(document).on('click', function (e) {
        $('.dw-notifications').removeClass('open');
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.dw-notifications', function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
});

//custom time diff
function dw_human_time_diff( from = false, to = false) {
    if ( !from || !to ) {
        return false;
    }
    var  constants =dwnotif.dwnotif_constants;

    var diff = parseInt(Math.abs( to - from ));

    if ( diff < constants.HOUR_IN_SECONDS ) {
        var mins = Math.round( diff / constants.MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );
        if ( mins <= 1 )
            mins = 1;
        /* translators: Time difference between two dates, in minutes (min=minute). 1: Number of minutes */
        var since = mins==1? mins +' min' : mins +' mins';
    }  else if ( diff < constants.DAY_IN_SECONDS && diff >= constants.HOUR_IN_SECONDS ) {
        var hours = Math.round( diff / constants.HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
        if ( hours <= 1 )
            hours = 1;
        /* translators: Time difference between two dates, in hours. 1: Number of hours */
        var since = hours==1? hours +' hour' : hours +' hours';
    }  else if ( diff < constants.WEEK_IN_SECONDS && diff >= constants.DAY_IN_SECONDS ) {
        var days = Math.round( diff / constants.DAY_IN_SECONDS );
        if ( days <= 1 )
            days = 1;
        /* translators: Time difference between two dates, in days. 1: Number of days */
        var since = days==1? days +' day' : days +' days';
    }  else if ( diff < constants.MONTH_IN_SECONDS && diff >= constants.WEEK_IN_SECONDS ) {
        var weeks = Math.round( diff / constants.WEEK_IN_SECONDS );
        if ( weeks <= 1 )
            weeks = 1;
        /* translators: Time difference between two dates, in weeks. 1: Number of weeks */
        var since = weeks==1? weeks +' week' : weeks +' weeks';
    }  else if ( diff < constants.YEAR_IN_SECONDS && diff >= constants.MONTH_IN_SECONDS ) {
        var months = Math.round( diff / constants.MONTH_IN_SECONDS );
        if ( months <= 1 )
            months = 1;
        /* translators: Time difference between two dates, in months. 1: Number of months */
        var since = months==1? months +' month' : months +' months';
    }  else if ( diff >= constants.YEAR_IN_SECONDS ) {
        var years = Math.round( diff / constants.YEAR_IN_SECONDS );
        if ( years <= 1 )
            years = 1;
        /* translators: Time difference between two dates, in years. 1: Number of years */
        var since = years==1? years +' year' : years +' years';
    }
    return since;
}


function setCookie(cname, cvalue, extimes) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (extimes*1000)); // extimes second
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: I'm on my phone so I can't write you out a full solution but you need to remove the call to `autocheck()` after the variables and replace it with a click event for whatever selector will target the notifications list toggle.  Then put a call to the `checkNotifications()` function inside it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, I'll waiting you back :), cuz i still newbie with that, I see my ajax calling every 1 or 2 seconds :(, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the call to `autocheck()` with the following.

```
$('#ID-of-button').on('click', checkNotifications());
```

Of course you must replace `ID-of-button` with the ID of the toggle button for the notification bar.  This will run the ajax call when the button is clicked, open or close.

Comment: Thank you @mrben522, I removed all autocheck call and replaced as you said but not working! I still seeing the ajax calling every 2 second, and i don't know which part doing this :(.

Comment: Hello, Any hope to fix that!

Comment: Try removing the call to `autocheck(changed)` inside `checkNotifications`.  That might do it